# Problem Parsing request body of type json, containing a list of string to Flux of string in Spring reactive

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-webflux, reactive-mongo-java

I have a DTO as below:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InternetPackageDto {
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String termsAndConditions;

    private String price;

    private Flux<String> packageAttributes;

    private Flux<String> extras;
}
```

And a Database Object as below:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Document("internet_packages")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InternetPackage {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String termsAndConditions;

    private String price;

    private Flux<StoreableAttribute> attributes;

    private Flux<StoreableAttribute> extras;
}
```

The StorableAttribute Database Model like so:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document("package_attributes")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StoreableAttribute {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String description;
}
```

On the Data Object the fields: `Flux<StoreableAttribute> attributes` and `Flux<StoreableAttribute> extras` are stored in a separate collection alongside the Package Object. And is handled by the mapper as below:

```
 public InternetPackage fromDto(InternetPackageDto dto) {
        var internetPackage = new InternetPackage();

        internetPackage.setName(dto.getName());
        internetPackage.setPrice(dto.getPrice());
        internetPackage.setId(dto.getId());
        internetPackage.setExtras(this.resolePackageExtras(dto));
        internetPackage.setAttributes(this.resolePackageAttributes(dto));

        return internetPackage;
    }

  private Flux<StoreableAttribute> resolePackageExtras(InternetPackageDto dto) {
        return this.storeableAttributeService.resolveAttributes(dto.getExtras());
    }
```

for the extra and similarly for the attributes also.

And a simple controller method as below:

```
    @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<InternetPackageDto> update(@RequestBody InternetPackageDto incomingPackageDto) {
        return this.packageService
                .updatePackage(this.dtoMapper.fromDto(incomingPackageDto))
                .map(this.dtoMapper::toDto);
    }
```

And when I make a post request I get an error stating

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class reactor.core.publisher.Flux]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `reactor.core.publisher.Flux` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 2, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.example.api.dto.InternetPackageDto["extras"])
```

Some more information:

1. I am using the class `InternetPackageDto` as a request object as well as a response object.
2. I am using `Flux<String>` and not `List<String>` since I wasn't sure if doing blocking resolution to list was a good idea.
3. The attributes are stored and managed separately.
4. And during the time of updating or inserting the package those; if a new extra or attribute is included the attributes collection in db will be updated with the insertion of new incoming extras and attributes.

It seems like I might have made a stupid mistake because I cannot find much information about this problem, or I am doing it completely wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I understand, Jackson says "I can't serialize Flux.class". That is because Flux is not a data structure, it's a stream that could be infinite.

Comment: IS InternetPackage  stored in mongo? Can you point me to documentation of library which says you need to define flux in properties?

Comment: Yes `InternetPackage` is stored in DB. I am not sure if I can find any documentation of that sort. What I am doing here is trying to store `InternetPackage` in db as well as update the attributes and extras (which are stored in another db collection) incoming from the received `InternetPackageDto`. So store the package and if there are any extras and attributes available with package which are not already stored then store them too (in a separate collection to package collection).

Comment: Ok then let me try to update my answer.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try?

Comment: @zambliner hey mate did you have a chance to check?

Comment: Hey Thanks for help. But I was not able fix the problem as it was explained. I instead madde it work by changing the DTO to not return the Flux and return the list instead. So I did the updates with fire and forget principle. Which ist still not as I wanted to do.

Comment: But thats basically what i suggested :D you cant return flux in dto

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do smth like this

```
public Mono<InternetPackageDto> toDto(InternetPackage entity) {
    var internetPackage = new InternetPackageDto();

    internetPackage.setName(entity.getName());
    internetPackage.setPrice(entity.getPrice());
    internetPackage.setId(entity.getId());


    return Mono.zip(Mono.just(internetPackage), entity.getExtras().collectList(), entity.getAttributes().collectList())
            .flatMap(tu->{
                var dto = tu.getT1();
                dto.setExtras(tu.getT2()); //To make it work in my local i made entity.getAttributes() as Flux<String> so here you will probably need to use .stream().map(dbItem->dbItem.getPropertyName())
                dto.setPackageAttributes(tu.getT2());
                return Mono.just(dto);
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vova. But the fileds `packageAttributes` and `extras` are stored in database since they too can be managed independently. So each time a package is added the mapper will look if the mentioned fields are already stored in db or not if not already in db then will insert them. changing the resolver to work with the List would look like so: `this.storeableAttributeService.resolveAttributes(Flux.fromIterable(dto.getExtras())).collectList().block();` which I want to avoid to have this blocking call.

Comment: @zambliner Check now